# Q: How to find a section from a web page without using XPath

Tags: php, html, dom, domdocument

I need to extract a section from a web page. I need a version with DOM API and without XPath. This is my version. Need to extract from "Latest Distributions" and display the information in browser.

```
<?php
$result = file_get_contents ('https://distrowatch.com/');

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($result);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$node = $xpath->query('//table[@class="News"]')->item(0);

echo $node->textContent;
```

Comment: What's wrong with XPath? This seems like an artificial limitation. What have you tried?

Comment: It is a requirement of the exercise.

Comment: So I’m doing your homework. Wonderful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems pretty straightforward, but it's a waste of time to do this instead of XPath.

```
<?php
$result = file_get_contents ('https://distrowatch.com/');

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($result);
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName("table") as $table) {
    if ($table->getAttribute("class") === "News") {
        echo $table->textContent;
        break;
    }
}
```